# How to inject Http in Angular 2 without typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

The examples given by the angular team only show how to inject Http for typescript.

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html

What's the JS equivalent of this:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
```

and this:

```
constructor(http: Http) { }
```

Comment: Why do you inject `HttpFactory`? It's not mentioned in the page you linked to.

Comment: whoops, too many tabs open. Copied from the wrong one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're at alpha 49 or newer (you should be at least at beta.0) and you're using the UMD bundles the correct answer is to use `ng.http.Http` and `ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS`

```
var App = ng.core.
          Class({
            constructor: [ng.http.Http, function(http) {
              /* Do something with http */
            }]
          });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(App, [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
});
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pq6I8ExK9oIGQdEGQ2Aj?p=preview) with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ES6 (but not TypeScript), you need to create a getter for the parameters field:

```
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(http) {}

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```